# Permission denied when deleting directory in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a task which simply creates directory in the home directory of user 'foo' as follows:

```
---
- name: Create bar directory
  become: yes
  become_user: foo
  file:
    path: "/home/foo/bar"
    state: directory
    owner: foo
    group: foo
    mode: 755
```

This works fine, but when I try to run a task to delete the directory created by above task, I got the following error:

> TASK: [a task | Create bar directory]
>
> ---
>
> failed: [192.168.50.4] => {"failed": true}
>   msg: rmtree failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/foo/bar'
>
> FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

Below is the delete task.

```
---
- name: Create bar directory
  become: yes
  become_user: foo
  file:
    path: "/home/foo/bar"
    state: absent
```

I confirmed the created directory is owned by 'foo' so the directory should be able to be deleted by 'foo'. Why am I getting permission denied error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the directory is owned by the correct user, I realized that the permission for the directory was not correctly set, i.e, `drwxr-xr-x`.
The problem was `mode: 755`, which does not seem to be a problem at all. But I needed to prepend `0` before `755` in order for it to work as expected.
[Example in official document](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html#examples)